# Twitter SDK for objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, twitter

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Twitter SDK on iOS with standard UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597321/twitter-sdk-on-ios-with-standard-ui)
>   [Send a tweet from iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558622/send-a-tweet-from-iphone-app)
>   [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

Is there a twitter SDK available for iOS?  I checked their website but i can't find anything. I know that iOS 5 will have integrated twitter support, but what about ios4?

Thanks

Comment: No it's different. This question is referring to accessing the Twitter APIs themselves, whereas the "Twitter SDK on iOS with standard UI" question is referring to a UI framework for Twitter APIs.

Comment: Did you see the link at the bottom of the Twitter home page that says ["Developers"](http://dev.twitter.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#objectivec for some Objective-C client libraries. I haven't actually used any of these myself, but from what I hear the first option ([MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/)) does the job nicely.

Alternatively, you can find a tutorial for DIY from scratch [here](http://brandontreb.com/objective-c-programming-tutorial-creating-a-twitter-client-part-1/) (although, it is a bit dated, no OAuth for example).

Answer (score 0):

In iOS4, you can use NSURLConnection instances to talk to the Twitter API, and decode the returned JSON or XML. There are definitely good JSON decoder classes online for Objective-C, but many of the (pre-built) 'Twitter' classes, which wrap the API callbacks in a nice class, available online are now outdated as they are not maintained. If I were to recommend one, it would be the [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/), as this is maintained by Matt Gemmell, a prolific and reliable iOS developer - who obviously cares for the platform. He works on Twitterrific, which uses the MGTwitterEngine class, for instance; the likelihood of it being maintained is quite high.